# Using MATLink with an interactive MATLAB session on MacOS

Tags: interoperability, matlab

I just discovered [`MATLink`](http://matlink.org) and it's awesome. The only problem I have is that using `OpenMATLAB[]` opens a MATLAB session in the background and not the interactive GUI. So the only way I have to interact with this session is through Mathematica (via MATLink) and not directly, which is what I want to do. Is there any way to link Mathematica to an interactive MATLAB instance?

(I'm on Mac Sierra, Mathematica Version 11.0.1, MATLAB R2016b)

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [(69937)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69937/731)

Comment: @C.E. Thanks! this is exactly what I need, but unfortunately the `AutomationServer` is [only available on Windows systems](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/enableservice.html#br4v7wg-3). Is there a solution for Mac?

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this, including contacting the MathWorks support. There is no documented API that we could use to implement this feature on OS X.

Comment: What's annoying is that they do provide this feature in their Python API, which uses an undocumented internal C++ API that would be just too much trouble to reverse engineer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible on macOS and Linux due to the limitations of the MATLAB Engine C API.

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/39703491/695132

Comment: Bummer. Thanks.